# Converting name to a key using radix-26

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

> ```
> //Convert a name to a key using radix-26:
>   //Use all of the letters of the alphabet as your digits.
>   //Assume we only deal with lower-case letters for simplicity.
>   //Then you can create the radix(base)-26 alphabet number system.
>   //For example:
>   // "alice" in radix-26 is 26^4*1 + 26^3*12 + 26^2*9 + 26^1*3 + 26^0*5 = 674055
>   // "zoe" in radix-26 is 26^2*26 + 26^1*15 + 26^0*5 = 17971 
>  static long nameToKey(String name) {
>       long key = 0;
>       /**
>        * TODO
>        */
>       for (int i = 0;i<name.length();i++)
>           key+= (name.charAt(i) - 'A' ) * Math.pow(26,name.length() - i - 1 );
>       return key;
>
>
>       //return 0;
>   }
> ```

Output expected for `alice is 674055` but my `output is 15406960`
I don't understand what logic error I'm making. If someone could please help me.

Comment: alice is ancient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using ***lower-case*** letters. This

```
name.charAt(i) - 'A'
```

should be

```
name.charAt(i) - 'a'
```

But to get the result you specify you must add one.

```
key += (name.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1) * Math.pow(26, name.length() - i - 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this, which doesn't involve the `pow` function, and that I find simpler, is:

```
long key = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i)
{
    key = (key * 26) + name.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1;
}
return key;
```